# Android Pass Data to Activity via ContextMenu Item

Tags: android, android-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

I'm implementing a PoC app for Android where I've got a  Context Menu that open on long click. It's got two options: "Update", and "Delete". If the user selects the "Update" option, I'd like to open a new `Activity` with the data available in `EditText` widgets, and ready for alteration.
I've been able to handle the navigation to a new `Activity` within an `onContextItemSelected` method by checking the `MenuItem` IDs, but I can't find any way to pass the data along.

Thanks,
Debojit

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) (not sure it's relevant, but I think so)

Comment: @Keyser: Thanks for the link, but the question you pointed me to was simple about passing data between activities directly. My workflow is like this(approx.): Activity1 -> Context Menu -> Context Menu Item Selection Handler -> Activity2

Comment: I suspected as much  shortly after posting...Sry, can't help.

Comment: That answer will still work. Your onContextItemSelected method belongs to an Activity, after all.